# Instance methods called in a separate thread than the instantiation thread

Tags: python, multithreading, wxpython, twisted

I'm trying to wrap my head around what is happening in [this recipe](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/286201/), because I'm planning on implementing a wx/twisted app similar to this (ie. wx and twisted running in separate threads).  I understand that both twisted and wx event-loops need to be accessed in a thread-safe manner (ie. reactor.callFromThread, wx.PostEvent, etc).  What I am questioning is the thread-safety of passing in instance methods of objects instantiated in one thread (in the case of this recipe, the GUI thread) as deferred callBack and errBack methods for a reactor running in a separate thread.  Is that a good idea?

There is a wxreactor available in twisted, but googling reveals that there have been numerous problems with it since it was introduced to the library.  Even the person who initially came up with the wxreactor technique, [advocates running wx and twisted in separate threads](http://twistedmatrix.com/pipermail/twisted-python/2005-April/010113.html).

I haven't been able to find any other examples of this technique, but I'd love to see some.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wouldn't say that it's a "good idea".  You should just run the reactor and the GUI in the same thread with wxreactor.

The timer-driven event-loop starving approach described by Mr. Schroeder is the worst possible fail-safe way to implement event-loop integration.  If you use `wxreactor` (not `wxsupport`) Twisted now uses an approach where multiplexing is shunted off to a thread internally so that nothing needs to use a timer.  Better yet would be for wxpython to expose `wxSocket` and have someone base a reactor on it.

However, if you're set on using a separate thread to communicate with Twisted, the one thing to keep in mind is that while you can use objects that originate from any thread you like as the value to pass to `Deferred.callback`, you must *call* `Deferred.callback` only in the reactor thread itself.  Deferreds are not threadsafe; thanks to some debugging utilities, not even the `Deferred` *class* is threadsafe, so you need to be very careful when you are using them to never leave the Twisted main thread.  i.e. when you have a result in the UI thread, use `reactor.callFromThread(myDeferred.callback, myresult)`.

Answer (score 0):

The sole act of passing instance methods between threads is safe as long as you properly synchronize eventual destruction of those instances (threads share memory so it really doesn't matter which one did the allocation/initialization of a bit of it).

The overall thread safety depends on what those methods actually do, so just make them "play nice" and you should be ok.